# configure psk_ke (PSK-only) mode in TLS1.3

Tags: openssl, tls1.3

I am using openssl 1.1.1 and trying to configure psk_ke (PSK-only) mode only in requests generated through s_client. In my requests, in client hello message,  I am not able to suppress psk_dhk_ke mode, which I think is getting added by default.

I have used  directive -allow_no_dhe_kex in s_client requests. It is only helping to get the psk_ke mode added in the packet.

Also the options like ec_point format, key share, signature algorithms are added in the client hello message which I think is due to psk_dhk_ke option included in client hello. Please correct my understanding if I am wrong.

Can psk_dhe_ke be suppressed in client hello along with ec_point format, key share, signature algorithms?

TCP dump of TLS1.3 client hello message:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to suppress psk_dhe_ke with OpenSSL when using TLSv1.3. The "-allow_no_dhe_kex" option only allows the peer to select the no-dhe version, but doesn't suppress sending the dhe option.

It is possible to suppress the ec_point_formats, signature_algorithms and key_share extensions in OpenSSL under certain circumstances - but not if you plan to do TLSv1.3. If you want to do TLSv1.3 then they will always be sent.

Comment: Thank you Matt for sharing opinion. Could you please comment on ec_point_formats , signature_algorithms  and key_share extensions as well. Are they dependent on psk_dhe_ke and is it possible to suppress them in s_client requests.

Comment: I extended my answer to cover those extensions too.